# R: Can judge significance based on overlap in graph produced by dotplot(ranef(model))?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I would like to know whether I can use the graph produced by `dotplot(ranef(model))` to judge wether the random effects are significant or not.

GMA is my random effect in this case. I have edited out the y axis values, but every line belongs to a crop cultivar.

Can I say, based on this plot that, due to overlap with 0, that the upper 8 cultivars have a significant postive GMA, the middle 9 cultivars a non-significant GMA and the bottom 7 a significantly negative GMA.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Showing the plot may be helpful.

Comment: I have added the plot now.

Comment: thanks but your post is still unclear. Please explain what is the problem, the model you are considering and why you want such a test. Maybe that issue can be solved differently...Testing for significant random effects is a non standard procedure and I'm not sure it's duable in a frequentist setting because the random effects are not parameters in the standard frequentist approach.

Comment: The model is quite simple: model = yield ~ 1 + Location + (1|GMA)
The method is described here (It uses a specific package, plantmix, with a modified lmer function, but I dont think that important for my question: 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378429018311675

I run the the modified lmer function and extract BLUPs as such: blup_gma1 = ranef(fit1)$GMA[,1]

These BLUPS correspond to the blue dots. The plot (dotplot(ranef(fit1)) also gives me errorbars. I want to know if I can infer significant differences in BLUPS or significantly different than 0 from this plot.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an appropriate way to evaluate if including the random effects improves the model fit. You could formally test that with a likelihood ratio test by comparing the model with and without the random effects. In R, this is done via the `anova()` function.

Comment: My question was different, but I did not ask it clear enough. I have updated my question and added the plot.